# Limiting values in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a script that takes a file containing the names of actors and movies, and construct hashes of the actors that were in each movie. Below is my current code, and I want to limit the size of my dictionary to 10 ie. only the first 10 actors in each movie can be added into the dictionary. I tried a loop and break and my method did not work.

Update, I tried to incorporate @jonrsharpe's suggestion, but it just simply slices up my dictionary without restricting the list of actors for each movie to 10:

```
movietoactorfile = open('mov2act.pickle', 'w')
movietoactor = {}

for line in gzip.open(moviefile_name, 'rb').readlines():
  (actor, movie, rank) = line.rstrip('\r\n\s').split('\t')
  if movie not in movietoactor:
    movietoactor[movie] = []
  movietoactor[movie].append(actor)

for movie in movietoactor:
  s = "\t".join(movietoactor[movie][:10])

pickle.dump(movietoactor, movietoactorfile)
```

Oringinal sample output:

```
S'Irma la Douce (1963)'
p1
S"\tDeauville, Sheryl\tEarl, Jane\tEarl, Ruth\tHoliday, Hope\tMacLaine, Shirley\tSatana, Tura\tShawlee, Joan\tWhitney, Grace Lee\tWoods, Susan (I)\tYoung, Harriette\tAlvin, John (I)\tBarrier, Edgar\tBeck, Billy (I)\tBernardi, Herschel\tBixby, Bill\tBrown, James (II)\tCaan, James\tDiamond, Don\tDubov, Paul\tJacobi, Lou\tJourdan, Louis (I)\tKrugman, Lou\tLemmon, Jack (I)\tLerner, Diki\tMcNear, Howard\tMoustache\tO'Dell, Doye\tOsmond, Cliff\tPalma, Joe\tPeel, Richard\tYarnell, Bruce"
p2
sS'American Buffalo (1996)'
p3
S'\tFranz, Dennis (I)\tHoffman, Dustin\tNelson, Sean (I)'
```

Current output from the above code:

```
S'Irma la Douce (1963)'
p1
(lp2
S'Deauville, Sheryl'
p3
aS'Earl, Jane'
p4
aS'Earl, Ruth'
p5
aS'Holiday, Hope'
p6
aS'MacLaine, Shirley'
p7
aS'Satana, Tura'
p8
aS'Shawlee, Joan'
p9
aS'Whitney, Grace Lee'
p10
aS'Woods, Susan (I)'
p11
aS'Young, Harriette'
p12
aS'Alvin, John (I)'
p13
aS'Barrier, Edgar'
p14
aS'Beck, Billy (I)'
p15
aS'Bernardi, Herschel'
p16
aS'Bixby, Bill'
p17
aS'Brown, James (II)'
p18
aS'Caan, James'
p19
aS'Diamond, Don'
p20
aS'Dubov, Paul'
p21
aS'Jacobi, Lou'
p22
aS'Jourdan, Louis (I)'
p23
aS'Krugman, Lou'
p24
aS'Lemmon, Jack (I)'
p25
aS'Lerner, Diki'
p26
aS'McNear, Howard'
p27
aS'Moustache'
p28
aS"O'Dell, Doye"
p29
aS'Osmond, Cliff'
p30
aS'Palma, Joe'
p31
aS'Peel, Richard'
p32
aS'Yarnell, Bruce'
p33
asS'American Buffalo (1996)'
p34
(lp35
S'Franz, Dennis (I)'
p36
aS'Hoffman, Dustin'
```

The desired output should like this:

```
S'Irma la Douce (1963)'
p1
S"\tDeauville, Sheryl\tEarl, Jane\tEarl, Ruth\tHoliday, Hope\tMacLaine, Shirley\tSatana, Tura\tShawlee, Joan\tWhitney, Grace Lee\tWoods, Susan (I)\tYoung, Harriette"
p2
sS'American Buffalo (1996)'
p3
S'\tFranz, Dennis (I)\tHoffman, Dustin\tNelson, Sean (I)'
```

As for the suggestion to place the i = 1 outside of for line, that was the very 1st edit I tried before I post my question here and that did not work:

```
movietoactorfile = open('mov2act.pickle', 'w')
movietoactor = {}

i = 1
for line in gzip.open(moviefile_name, 'rb').readlines():
  (actor, movie, rank) = line.rstrip('\r\n\s').split('\t')
  if movie not in movietoactor:
    movietoactor[movie] = ''
  movietoactor[movie] += '\t%s' % actor
  i += 1
  if i > 10:
    break

pickle.dump(movietoactor, movietoactorfile)
```

Output:

```
S'\tactor'
p6
sS'Queen of the Damned (2002)'
p7
S'\tAaliyah'
p8
sS'Kauas pilvet karkaavat (1996)'
p9
S'\tAaltonen, Minna'
p10
sS'Class Act (1992)'
p11
S'\tAalda, Mariann'
p12
sS'Twenty Bucks (1993)'
p13
S'\tAabel, Per (II)'
p14
sS'South Pacific (1958)'
p15
S'\tAadland, Beverly'
p16
sS'Tomorrow Never Dies (1997)'
p17
S'\tAaltonen, Minna'
p18
sS'Romeo Must Die (2000)'
p19
S'\tAaliyah'
p20
s.
```

Comment: In the code that you show, you don't try to limit. Can you please give the version where you tried to limit, and tell what you mean by "did not work"?

Comment: If you only want to limit it to ten why not store a list for each movie and test the length of the list?

Comment: @EdChum Don't you think i is getting reset to 1 with each iteration of the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reset `i` to 1 each time through the `for` loop; the minimal fix is to move it outside:

```
i = 1
for line in gzip.open(moviefile_name, 'rb').readlines():
```

**Edit**: this doesn't work, because you have more than one movie in the file. You could have a separate count for each movie, but you might as well just skip to part 2:

---

This would all be easier if you used a list for each `movie`:

```
if movie not in movietoactor:
    movietoactor[movie] = []
if len(movietoactor[movie]) < 10:
    movietoactor[movie].append(actor)
```

If your other script is also in Python, there is no need to try to *parse* the pickled file, just use `pickle.load` to return to the actual data structure. You can leave the data in lists, and they will be restored in the other script, rather than needing to e.g. `split('\t')`. This makes manipulation much easier, and is the whole point of using `pickle.`

If it isn't Python, there are probably easier formats to use for the transfer - a `csv`, for example, where each line starts with the movie name then has up to ten actors:

```
'American Buffalo (1996)','Franz, Dennis (I)','Hoffman, Dustin','Nelson, Sean (I)'
```

Alternatively, look into `json`.

If you *really, really* want to stick with what you have, you can convert each list to a string before you `pickle`:

```
for movie in movietoactor:
    movietoactor[movie] = "\t".join(movietoactor[movie])
```

Comment: If the file contains multiple movies, you don't want to `break` when the limit for one of them is hit. Instead, add actors without limit and just build the string from a slice with at most ten of them, rather than the full list, e.g.: `s = "\t".join(movietoactor[movie][:10])`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it doesn't work (see the edit).

Comment: @user3440320 firstly, you have to *do something* with `s`, just creating it doesn't get you anywhere. Secondly, why are you worrying to much about what's in the pickled file? It's not meant to be readable, it's meant to be unpicklable!

Comment: I have another script that reads the hashes to find paths between actors connected by the movie they were in eg. Bacon,Kevin => Wild Things (1998) => Dillon, Matt (I) => Beautiful Girls (1996) => Portman, Natalie. My purpose to restrict the number of actors is to observe how the paths changes between any 2 actors.

Comment: @user3440320 then why not unpickle the file in your other script? You can leave the actors in lists (shortened with `[:10]` at one end or the other) and save yourself the parsing at the other end.

Comment: @user3440320 I have updated my answer to give you a few options. I would not recommend using `pickle` as a general data transfer format, there are better options!

Comment: Thank you, your suggestions work. Yes, I'm using pickle.load in my other script, and I'm learning how data manipulation with pickle works.